# Building a dmaap filter on a csv list?

Tags: groovy, filter, get

I am attempting to subscribe to a DMAAP service and data can be filtered along the Highland Park Filter library, which is JSON based.  What I need to do is filter on a value coming back, in this case, a state.  We have a field called "deliveryState" which is the two-character state code.  I would like to be able to filter on a series of states but for the life of me I haven't been able to do this, either I can filter on a single state, or on no states.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so we can improve on it.

Comment: I sort of solved this.  How do I put code in here?  It keeps limiting the characters I type.  Here's an abbreviated example:

?filter={ "class":"Or", "filters":
   [ {"class":"Equals", "field":"State", "value":"FL" },{"class":"Equals", "field":"State", "value":"NY" },{"class":"Equals", "field":"State", "value":"CO" },{"class":"Equals", "field":"State", "value":"SC" }]}

You can't do multiple values but you can "stack"

Comment: It's encouraged to add an answer with the solution you came up on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well it looks like you pass in a JSON value as part of the header:

```
?filter={ "class":"Or", "filters": [ {"class":"Equals", "field":"State", "value":"FL" },{"class":"Equals", "field":"State", "value":"NY" },{"class":"Equals", "field":"State", "value":"CO" },{"class":"Equals", "field":"State", "value":"SC" }]}
```

You can't have multiple values but you can "stack" your filters.  In this case, I'm doing it to only allow values with the "State" field equal to FL, NY, CO, or SC.